# Add multiple values to disabled attribute in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add values to a **disabled** directive. So if you look at the code below I am disabling a button if a value matches `System Admin`. I am now trying to add more values to this. So I want to add `System Admin` and `HR Manager` to this.

```
[disabled]="userRole === 'System Admin'"
```

I tried this but it does not seem to work

```
[disabled]="userRole === 'System Admin' || 'HR Manager'"
```

Comment: Hope it will work if you add parentheses `[disabled]="(userRole === 'System Admin' || 'HR Manager')"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have many conditions to check then its better to write a function which will return `true` or `false`:

**HTML**:

```
[disabled]="isDisabled(userRole)"
```

**Typescript**:

```
isDisabled(userRole:string):boolean {
  if(userRole == "System Admin" || userRole == "HR Manager") {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: NVM, But in this way we are having a performance issues bcs `isDisabled` is continuously call  when ever the change is detected.

Comment: @YashRami Since it is in a loop, whenever change is detected, ternary operator condition will also be continuously called. As per my knowledge, calling the function won't create any additional performance issue, it's same even if it is written in view

Comment: @AdritaSharma If you loop over 1000 records then It actually blocks the UI and makes page unresponsive! See demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqjquc)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
[disabled]="(userRole === 'System Admin' || userRole === 'HR Manager') ? true : false"
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that:

```
userRole === 'System Admin' || 'HR Manager'
```

means

```
if (userRole === 'System Admin') return true;
else return 'HR Manager';
```

So you can use this:

```
['System Admin','HR Manager'].indexOf(userRole) !== -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare one thing with multiple things if that are strings *(as per my knowledge)*, so need to modify the condition like this:

```
[disabled]="userRole === 'System Admin' || userRole === 'HR Manager'"
```

The problem with Custom function to disable the control, it calls multiple times (Called even if you click on the control):

[image]

So if there are only two values to compare then I would use HTML Code Approach

[`Stackblitz_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqjquc)